# Volume of parallelepiped given three parallel planes

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, 3d, volume, cross-product

> Prove that the volume of the parallelepiped formed by the planes: $a_i x + b_i y + c_i z = p_i$, $a_i x + b_i y + c_i z = q_i$ , $i= \{1,2,3 \}$ is
> $$ \left|\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{3} (p_i - q_i)}{\begin{vmatrix} a_{1} & b_{1} & c_{1} \\ a_{2} & b_{2} & c_{2} \\ a_{3} & b_{3} & c_{3} \end{vmatrix}} \right|$$

I tried by calculating the equation of line of intersections of any two parallel planes, with another non parallel plane; the length of the edge by calculating the the distance between the above two lines of intersections, measured parallel to the plane cutting the two parallel planes. However this approach is getting really messy, and I think that calculating the box product/scalar triple product with the three edges is really lengthy.

Is there a short/simple way to do this question?

I know that a similar Question has been asked here [How to find volume of a parallelepiped if all six planes are given?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2458995/how-to-find-volume-of-a-parallelepiped-if-all-six-planes-are-given)
However the above formula hasn't been derived there and the method presented there still seems to be quite lengthy.

Comment: How I would try to do it : find out the 3 vectors which make the parallelipiped, then calculate their determinant (since the determinant can be defined as the (oriented) volume of the parallelipiped made by three vectors)

Comment: @Nephanth That's exactly what I was trying to do. However it was getting really messy

Comment: Seems to be a MathJax bug there $-$ the outer vertical bars are much too tall, at least on Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the matrix
$$M= {\begin{bmatrix} a_{1} & b_{1} & c_{1} \\ a_{2} & b_{2} & c_{2} \\ a_{3} & b_{3} & c_{3} \end{bmatrix}}
$$
and consider its effect on points on the surface of the parallelepiped:

- Points $P=(x,y,z)$ on the first bounding plane satisfy $a_1x+b_1y+c_1z=p_1$, so the $x$-coordinate of $MP$ is $p_1$.
- Similarly, points $Q=(x,y,z)$ on the second bounding plane satisfy $a_1x+b_1y+c_1z=q_1$, so the $x$-coordinate of $MQ$ is $q_1$.

Thus the first pair or parallel planes transform under $M$ to two planes perpendicular to the $x$-axis and separated by a distance $|p_1-q_1|$.

Likewise the second pair of parallel planes transform under $M$ to two planes perpendicular to the $y$-axis and separated by a distance $|p_2-q_2|$; and the third pair of parallel planes transform under $M$ to two planes perpendicular to the $z$-axis and separated by a distance $|p_3-q_3|$.

So the parallelepiped transforms into a rectangular cuboid, of volume $V=\prod_{i=1}^{3} |p_i - q_i|$. And the inverse matrix $M^{-1}$ trasforms a solid of volume $V$ into the original parallelepiped.

Hence the volume of the parallelepiped is $|V\det(M^{-1})|=\left|\dfrac{V}{\det M}\right|$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer (+1). However I'm not able to quite understand your approach. What exactly do you mean by the transformations "x-coordinate of MP is p_1", "x coordinate of MQ is q_1. Are you considering the product of the matrices M with $\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}$ and what exactly is the resultant plane that is formed?

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing. The matrix $M$ sends points on the plane $a_1 x + b_1 y + c_1 z = p_1$ to points on the plane $x=p_1$.

Comment: Got it now! Thanks a lot! It's a really wonderful approach